# Sufficiency implies Sufficiency and Necessity

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, terminology

Is it correct to say that: if for a problem exist a sufficient condition, then will mandatorily exist a sufficient and necessary condition (even if we have not discovered it yet) ?

Comment: What you are asking is that if $A\implies B$, that is if $A$ is sufficient for $B$, then is there some $C$ such that $C\iff B$? Yes there is. Let $C$ be $B.$.... Whether or not we can find some $C$ (with $C\iff B$) which gives us more knowledge or insight about $B$ than we currently possess is another matter.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not always true.

For example if $x<5$, then $x<6$ but if $x<6$ we can not conclude that $x<5$ That is $x<5$ is sufficient for  $x<6$ but it is not necessary for $x<6$

Comment: I dont know why my question got down-voted ....